# Java code error "E cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, oop, generics

The following java code gives the error "E cannot be resolved to a type", how do I fix it?

`AbstractTree<E>` is an abstract method.

```
public class Driver {

     public int[] computeDepths(AbstractTree<E> T, int n) {
         int[] depths = new int[n];
         int i=0;
         //traverse the tree and compute the depth of each position
         for (Position<E> p : T.preorder())
         {
         depths[i] = T.depth(p);
         i+=1;
         }
         return depths;
     }
    
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        

    }
    
}
```

Comment: add `<E>` in front of the `int[]` return type like so:  `public <E> int[] computeDepths(AbstractTree<E> T, int n) {`. I can advice you to learn a bit about generics first before using it in your code.

Comment: Also don't use the letter `T` as an argument name. Its confusing! Only use letters for generic types.

Comment: What do you mean by "`AbstractTree<E>` is an abstract method"?  It doesn't look like any kind of method to me.

Comment: @Maurice More precisely a normal argument name begins with a *lowercase* letter (so `t` and `tree` are both OK). A *type argument* (between `<` and `>`) is usually a single *uppercase* latter (as `E` in the code posted, which is correct).

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? What are `AbstractTree` and `Position`? A [mre], please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the method generic, for example:

```
public <E> int[] computeDepths(AbstractTree<E> tree, int n) {
    // Code
}
```

Either the method or the class needs to be generic in order to use generic types within them.

When code calls the method, you either need the compiler to work out the type for you (for example, based on the specific abstract tree that is passed) or you need to specify it where it can't be inferred.